# Segmentation fault error trying to delete a node from linked list

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a method (`delete_at`) which deletes a node in a given position, but I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error. The weird thing is that the code works and effectively deletes the node I want, but I keep getting that error. The error is in `delete_at`, the other methods work fine.

Can anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

//each of the nodes of our list is a class
template <class T> class node {

    private:

        T data;

    public:

        node <T> *next;

        node(): data(NULL), next(NULL) {}
        node(T x): data(x), next(NULL) {}

        T get_data () {

            return (data);
        }
};

template <class T> class list {

    private:

        node <T> *head, *p, *last;

    public:

        list(): head(NULL), p(NULL), last(NULL) {}

        ~list () {

            node <T> *n;
            for (p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next) {

                n = p->next;
                delete (p);
                p = n;
            }
            delete (n);
            cout << "list destroyed." << endl;
        }

        bool is_empty () {

            return (head == NULL);
        }

        //inserts a node at the beginning of the list
        void append (T x) {

            p = new node <T> (x);

            if (head == NULL) {

                head = p;
                last = head;
            }
            else {

                p->next = head;
                head = p;
            }
        }

        //inserts a node at the end of the list
        void push (T x) {

            p = new node <T> (x);

            if (head == NULL) {

                head = p;
                last = head;
            }
            else {

                last->next = p;
                last = p;
            }
        }

        void pop () {

            if (is_empty())
                cout << "empty list.";
            else if (head == last)
                head = last = NULL;
            else {

                for (p = head; p->next != last; p = p->next);
                delete (last);
                last = p;
                last->next = NULL;
            }
        }

        void delete_at (int i) {

            if (is_empty())
                cout << "empty list.";
            else if (i < size()) {

                p = head;

                if (i == 0) {

                    head = p->next;
                    delete (p);
                }
                else {

                    for (int j=0; j < i-1; j++)
                        p = p->next;

                    node <T> *tmp = p->next;
                    if (tmp->next != NULL) {

                        p->next = tmp->next;

                    }
                    else {
                        last = p;
                        last->next = NULL;
                    }

                    delete (tmp);
                }
            }
            else
                cout << "Invalid index." << endl;
        }

        void print () {

            for (p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
                cout << p->get_data() << " ";

            cout << endl;
        }

        int size () {

            int size = 0;
            for (p = head; p != NULL; size++, p = p->next);
            return (size);
        }

        T operator [] (int index) {

            int i;
            for (i=0, p = head; i < index; p = p->next, i++);
            return (p->get_data());
        }
};

int main () {

    //initializing random seed
    srand (time(NULL));

    list <int> l;

    cout << "Is the list empty? " << l.is_empty() << endl;
    l.push(rand() % 100);
    l.push(rand() % 100);
    l.push(rand() % 100);
    l.append(rand() % 100);
    l.push (rand() % 100);
    cout << "Is the list still empty? " << l.is_empty() << endl;
    cout << "l[2] = " << l[2] << endl << endl;
    cout << "size of the list: " << l.size() << endl;
    l.print ();

    l.pop ();
    l.print();

    l.delete_at (0);
    l.print ();
    l.delete_at (10);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. It will point you straight to where the error occurred.

Comment: Your destructor is wrong. It skips nodes and may cause undefined behavior due to dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Another tip -- **don't** use random data when testing your classes.  The reason why is that if your class is not working, using random data just makes things harder.  Just use known values first -- once you get your class working, *then* you use random data.

Comment: `p` shouldn't be a member of the class. It's only used in loops of the member functions and doesn't actually store any data of the class, so declare it in the loops when you actually need it. You should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` whenever possible since it avoids possible mistakes like assigning `NULL` to an int. `rand()` is an outdated function. It is best to use the tools in the C++ `<random>` header to generate random numbers.

Comment: Please post an [mcve], emphasis on "complete". We should be able to reproduce the problem by running your code as is, without adding in functions which you left out such as `node::is_empty`, `node::push`, `node::pop`, `node::print`, and `node::append`. That way, we know that they aren't causing the problem. Also, you should use the C++ versions of the C header files such as `cstdlib` instead of `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs in your code. Do one small step at a time and test a lot.

Here are some problems and suggestions:

- If your list is empty and you call the destructor, then you will delete n which is uninitialized.
- In your destructor, you advance twice per loop iteration (once in the for statement and once in loop block) but you delete only one item. Thus, only about half the items are properly deleted.
- If you fix the above 2 problems, then you don't need to delete n after the loop.
- Your variable should be initialized at their first use whenever possible.
- In your `delete_at` function it does not make much sense to first ask the size as it cause the list to be iterated twice. In particular, if `i` is 0, the length is not much useful.
- If you call `delete_at(0)`for a list with a single item, you code won't properly update `last` and won't reset `head` to `nullptr`.
- It would probably be much easier to have a pointer `prev` initialized to `nullptr` and advance until you reach the desired index. At that point, you know if have to update the head (`prev` still nil) and/or the tail (`next` is nil for the item to remove).
- As mentionned in comments, `p` should not be a member variable.
- In `pop` if the list contain a single item, that item is not deleted.
- Given that the internal state might be incorrect (for ex. `last` not updated), it is hard to predict if something might goes wrong a few steps later.
- You should delete copy and move constructor ans assignment for your node class (and you list too) to ensure you don't call them accidently.
- Your default constructor do not initialize data. As it is not used, you might consider deleting it.

Also your question does not tell when the error occur since there are 2 `delete_at` call point in `main`. And it would be useful to provide the output you get.

I don't think it is necessary to add 5 items to get the crash so removing a few "update" to see if the crash still occurs would make it faster to reason about the actual state.

I would recommend you to do some unit testing. You should add a counter of object or output call to constructors/destructors at it would help detect missing deletion.

For you test, you could do the following:

- Create and destroy an empty list.
- Create, push an item, destroy the list
- Create, push an item, pop the item, destroy the list
- Create, push an item, delete item at index 0, destroy the list
- Repeat by appending an item instead of pushing it.
- Create an empty list and call pop, delete_at... on it.
- Add multiple items and remove some or all items.

For your test, you can simply test with specific values of `data` and check that you have the expected items at some point (and that you have properly delete the appropriate number of nodes).